# mongoose findById return null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm doing a to do list application. I use the following function to move a task in the to-do list to the done list. However, the "columnId" method I use as the url parameter and the "findById" method that I use return null. What do you think the problem might be?

```
public async Put(columnId: string, todo: ITodo): Promise<ITodo | null> {
    try {
        const editingTodo: ITodo | null = await Todo.findById(todo._id);
        if (editingTodo !== null) {
            const oldColumn: IColumn | null = await Column.findById(editingTodo.Column._id).exec();
            if (oldColumn !== null) {
                const todoIndexByOldColumn = oldColumn.Todos.indexOf(editingTodo._id);
                oldColumn.Todos.splice(todoIndexByOldColumn, 1);

                const newColumn: IColumn | null = await Column.findById(columnId).populate("Todos").exec();
                console.log(newColumn);
                if (newColumn !== null) {
                    newColumn.Todos.push(todo);
                    newColumn.save();
                    oldColumn.save();
                    editingTodo.save();
                }
            }
        }
        return editingTodo;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is crud operation for a todo list with mongoose.

```
// model todo 

 let todo = new schema({
    description: { type: String },
    heading: { type: String },
    title: { type: String },

 });
```

Below is the controller with logic for all operations.

```
// get All Todo List
let findAllTodoList = async (req, res, next ) => {
      let foundAllTodo = await todo.findAll({});
      res.send({ data: foundAllTodo });
 };

// get Specific Todo 
let findTodoById = async (req, res, next ) => {
      let todo_id = req.params.todo_id;
      let foundTodo = await todo.findById(todo_id);
      res.send({ data: foundTodo });
 };

// create Todo Element 
let createTodo = async (req, res, next ) => {
       let todo_obj =  {
          description: 'Here Add Element',
          heading: 'Adding',
          title: 'Add',
        };
      let foundTodo =  await todo.create(todo_obj);
      res.send({ data: 'success' });
 };

 // Destroy Todo Element 
let DeleteTodoById = async (req, res, next ) => {

      let todo_id = req.params.todo_id 
      let foundTodo =  await todo.remove({ _id:todo_id });
      res.send({ data: 'success' });
 };

module.exports = {
  findAllTodoList 
  findTodoById,
  createTodo,
  DeleteTodoById

};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but when I do it that way it returns null. What may be the problem

Comment: Try to use 
 " await todo.find({ _id: todo_id }); " or  " await todo.findOne({ _id: todo_id }); "